# not able to load maps just getting zoom panel at the bottom right corner

Tags: android, api, google-maps, maps

03-27 01:12:59.165: E/Google Maps Android API(22325): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
03-27 01:12:59.180: E/Google Maps Android API(22325): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.here, API Key: AIzaSyCTTRon5xakVgIQyIFT4MQr4KSg90ooqiI, Certificate Fingerprint: 10877C9DBB0BF1B5C84C28AC1859649A2C8CDBED
03-27 01:12:59.265: I/Google Maps Android API(22325): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
03-27 01:13:05.475: D/dalvikvm(22325): GC_CONCURRENT freed 420K, 5% free 10162K/10695K, paused 2ms+2ms
03-27 01:13:14.580: E/Google Maps Android API(22325): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Wrong API key it seems. Generate a new one on the Google Console API, just in case. Also if you for whatever reason changed the name of your application in the manifest, then it would deem the API key invalid too.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

have you followed the documentation precisely?

It seems that you use wrong keys, or not use them at all.